# $compile not compiling whole string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile html in my directive to move into a table via jquery.

For some reason my $compile does not grab this whole string, it just grabs the repeat directive.
If I remove the `<tr ng-repeat...>` it will grab the remaining string though.

```
var el = $compile('<tr ng-repeat="row in gotData" ><td>{{row["data"]}}</td> <td>{{row["moredata"] % 5 |number:3}}</td> <td>{{row["moredata2"] % 5 | number:3}}</td><td>{{row["moredata3"] % 5 | number: 3}}</td><td>{{row["moredata"] % 5 | number: 3}}</td></tr>')(scope)
```

I am logging the 'el' and I can see that it is lacking the complete string, it just has the the repeat directive located here in this key:

```
el['0']['data']
```

hoping this is possible.

Comment: is gotData a function or collection of items?

Comment: question - when do you load gotData? Outside directive or inside directive? If outside then check if you are running directive when ajax call is finished ( and values are bound to directive on finished ajax call which can be solved via ng-if directive )

Comment: gotData is available in the scope from the controller. I was hoping it could get it from the controllers scope and not from the directive's scope. However, the same object is on a isolated two-way binding scope '='.

Comment: If I were to access it in the directive it would be scope.data.gotData

Comment: please put all the code

Answer (score 2):

Look at this source from Angular docs.

```
var $compile = ...; // injected into your code
var scope = ...;
var parent = ...; // DOM element where the compiled template can be appended

var html = '<div ng-bind="exp"></div>';

// Step 1: parse HTML into DOM element
var template = angular.element(html);

// Step 2: compile the template
var linkFn = $compile(template);

// Step 3: link the compiled template with the scope.
var element = linkFn(scope);

// Step 4: Append to DOM (optional)
parent.appendChild(element);
```

You have to angularify the code before you compile it using $compile.

Hope, this will help. All the best.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nwu2bjtt/ I am not sure if I am replicating what you have here right but I can't append off parent. I was concerned parent was a key word so I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

```
var throbberHolder = document.getElementById("throbber-mask");
$compile(throbberHolder)(angular.element(throbberHolder).scope()); or 
$compile(throbberHolder)(throbberHolder.scope());
```

In that the `throbber-mask` will be the `id` of your `<tr>` element.

Comment: I will add a fiddle, scope is not available where it is being called.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o8v7jmwc/6/ I cleared them. the only one is a missing var for throbberHolder but when that exists it freezes the browser.